# Can can I avoid a TextInput losing focus when its parent's state changes?

Tags: react-native

When I update the state of my app's wrapper component

```
export default class App extends React.Component { // the primary component of the app
  state = {}
```

All `TextInput` components lose focus. How can I work around it? I've searched and there are tons of reports from years ago of this happening but those were all bug reports, surely the same bug doesnt exist years later, this must be intended behavior.

Comment: Please, provide some code example. How the parent is using that state? The only way I could reproduce was by setting a different key for the parent view.

Comment: @diogenesgg wow, that fixed it. A different key causes the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @diogenesgg suggested in his comment, having a different key assigned to the input than the parent causes the issue.